# Software development MANAGEMENT tools

Tags: software-development, project-management, time-management

I'm building a lab that people will use to build basic software concepts (prototypes) so they have something tangible to assess.

All types of software prototypes will be developed in there: from iOS to embedded, from beautiful looking GUIs to database management tools.

It is quite a herculean lab with a decent funding.

The question is simple though: What are the tools would be of help on TRACKING, MANAGING and PLANING the ongoing projects?

(I've really tried to narrow the question, hopefully it is not too vague)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm voting to close as 'too broad': *tracking, managing and planning* is so generic that any project management software will do. What is so specific to your projects that a generic project management program can't do?

Comment: Isn't it software recommendations? Give it a try =)

Comment: Yes, it is "Software Recommendations". And to give recommendations (and not just miles-long lists of names), there are certain requirements: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) So I agree with Jan, and second him.

Comment: This seems reasonable clear to me. OP wants a tool to give visibility over projects - what they involve, who's working on them, time frames, dependencies, etc?

Comment: Did the OP say so? I think that you are projecting. Correctly, as it happens :-) But we can all guess that much, and it is still as vague as Jan said. I think that OP really needs to give an explicit list of features, but my guess is that he doesn't really know enough about the subject - in which case, he would be better off googling & trying a  few out.

Comment: @Mawg, that's true, I do not know much about the subject. Would someone have any suggestions on how to narrow the question to a reasonable level? Then I would gladly edit the question ;)

Comment: @dwjohnston, you're right. We need the tools to have better visibility over projects. If someone gives me a kickstart I'll harvest a whole crop of valuable new ideas

Comment: Well, it goes against site rules to make recommendations for something so vaguer, but if you can't goggle yourself for project panning/management software, I generally use http://www.taskjuggler.org/  or https://www.openproject.org/  for planning & tracking. Do you also need bug reporting? really, though, you ought to google for this, or buy a general book on the subject from Amazon. It am guessing that you are the not too technical manager, trying to plan the centre, before you even have staff for it. If you don't know these things, then your staff will. Good luck

Comment: For ideas about a full s/w development tool-chain, see my old (outdated) post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020869/seeking-a-true-tool-chain